# How set a dynamic dataSource with mat-table with a ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm making a dashboard with Angular Material. On that dashboard I want to show a card for each server (so far so good) and within that card I want to show a table with the customers on that specific server. That's where I get stucked.

When use my code below, I get the following error (for every table):

```
ERROR Error: Could not find column with id "name".
```

My relevant code:

```html
<mat-card class="card" *ngFor="let listItem of serverList; let i = index">
  <mat-card-header>
    <div mat-card-avatar class="card-header-image"></div>
    <mat-card-title>{{listItem.name}} - {{ listItem.datasource }}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{listItem.url}} - {{listItem.status}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <div class="table-container mat-elevation-z8">
      <mat-table #table [dataSource]="listItem.datasource" matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="klant">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Klant </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.name }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.status }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

and:

```js
this.fbService.getServerList().subscribe( data => {
  this.serverList = data;
});
```

Note: I use Firestore to store the servers and customers.

Essencially my question is how can I set the [dataSource] dynamically:

```html
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="listItem.datasource" matSort>
```

?

Comment: Can you also post your ts? Even better, a stackblitz example

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and response. Unfortunately I could not get it working with the provided solution. I'll try to get it on StackBlitz...

Comment: I have same problem. Is there any solution for this?
*ngFor="let item of facilityGroups"
datasource=[item.values]
I want to set like this

Comment: I don't found any solution jet

Answer (score 0):

I believe the dataSource needs to be of type MatTableDataSource

You can instantiate a dataSource like so:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.myList);
```

Try and map the values after you receive them from your service:

```js
this.fbService.getServerList().subscribe(data => {
      this.serverList = data.map(el =>
        el.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(el.dataSource);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is similar, but I was using the Mat Accordion panel to group items and when expanded show a mat table of child items.

This was easy enough as the array of categories I was using had a child array of products.

```
*ngFor="let cat of categories let i = index;"
```

and on the table...

```
table mat-table [dataSource]="cat.products"
```

Doing it this way meant the accordion wasn't making a http call on click and it works as you would expect. The only fly in the ointment was updates.

Setting your table datasource as a iterated child array meant it didn't get assigned MatTableDataSource and you lost access to its methods update goodies.

Fear not Viewchildren comes to the rescue

```
  @ViewChildren(MatTable)
  tables: QueryList<MatTable<IProduct>>;
```

...which gives me access to all the tables in the view.

This should allow you to make table updates/deletions and manipulations. For instance if you have added a new row to you table call the renderRows method to have them appear in your table.

```
  refreshTables(): void {
    this.tables.forEach(tbl => tbl.renderRows());
  }
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this thou.  I hope it gives you a clue anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my project and I solved it by making a simple function.

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards | async" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="getDataSource(card.title)">
```

and in the typescript file

```
tableData1: MatTableDataSource<any>;
tableData2: MatTableDataSource<any>;


cards = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset).pipe(
    map(({ matches }) => {
      if (matches) {
        return [
          { title: 'Title 1', cols: 2, rows: 1 },
          { title: 'Title 2', cols: 2, rows: 1 },
        ];
      }

      return [
        { title: 'Title 1', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
        { title: 'Title 2', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
      ];
    })
  );

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.auth.user$.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.afs.collection('post', ref => ref.where('dateTime','>=', this.todayDate).where('createdBy', '==', this.user.uid)).valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
        this.tableData1 = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      });
this.afs.collection('post', ref => ref.where('dateTime','<=', this.todayDate).where('createdBy', '==', this.user.uid)).valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
        this.tableData2 = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      });
    });
    }
```

the function goes like this:

```
getDataSource(title) {
if(title==='Title 1') {
  return this.tableData1;
}
else return this.tableData2;
}
```

This simple function did the trick for me!